# translate require() syntax to import syntax node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, syntax

I am using strong-soap package in application. I am facing following syntax issue while translating require() to import statement.

```
var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
     to 
import soap from 'strong-soap.soap' // doesn't work also throwing syntax error
import soap from 'strong-soap';//not working as expected
```

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

soap is an object of `strong-soap` so the following would work -- ES6 modules importing.

```
import { soap } from 'strong-soap';
```